# How to prove that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{1}{2}}>e$ for all positive integer $n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

It has already been proved that
$$
\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n<\mathrm{e}<\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}
$$
The problem is to prove that the geometric average between $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ is still bigger than $\mathrm{e}$:
$$
\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}>\mathrm{e}
$$
One possible approach is to prove that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ strictly declines with $n$. Then, consider the limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}(n\to\infty)$ equals to $e$. But how to prove it? I need help.

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder what is the maximum $f(n)$ such that $(1+\frac1n)^{n+f(n)}<e$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4135375/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259175/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037414/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3730271/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bn%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%3E%5Cexact%7Be%7D%24)

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is an interesting way. I wonder if there are other alternative approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In comments, @BenjaminWang asked an interesting question :

*"What is the maximum $f(n)$ such that $(1+\frac1n)^{n+f(n)}<e$"*

The equality is given by
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}-n$$

Expanding as a series,
$$f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \,\frac {a_k}{b_k\,n^k}$$ where the $a_k$ and $b_k$ form sequences $A002206$ and $A002207$ in $OEIS$ (Gregory coefficients).

This gives as bounds

$$(1+\frac1n)^{n+f(n)}>e -\sum_{k=0}^{2p} (-1)^k \,\frac {a_k}{b_k\,n^k}=e\left(1-\frac{c_p}{n^{2p+2} }\right)$$

$$(1+\frac1n)^{n+f(n)}<e -\sum_{k=0}^{2p+1} (-1)^k \,\frac {a_k}{b_k\,n^k}=e\left(1+\frac{d_p}{n^{2p+3} }\right)$$ Moreover, coefficients $c_p$ and $d_p$ are not only small but also decreasing functions of $p$

Comment: The pattern in the expression of $f$ as a 5th-degree rational function is striking. Does it generalize?

Comment: @JohnBentin. In fact, the first I gave is the appropriate $[n,n]$ Padé approximant of the second. $OEIS$ did not find anything.

Comment: If the $c_p$ and $d_p$ do not depend on $n$ then those expressions tend to $\mathrm{e}$ for large $n$, but the expressions before them tend to $\mathrm{e}+1/2$. There is some syntax error there, you are also missing the $b_n$.

Comment: @Gary. Thanks for pointing !

Comment: I still don't understand those inequalities. What are the $a_k$? The order of magnitudes in $n$ do not match.

Comment: @Gary. I am really sorry ! Fixed (I hope)

Comment: I think it is still incorrect. Those series should appear in the exponential. Are you trying to say that succesive partial sums constitute upper and lower bounds to the actual $f(n)$?

Comment: @Gary. This is what I think ... but I may be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$f(x)=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x+\dfrac{1}{2}}, x\ge 1.$$
Then
$$ f'(x)=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x+\dfrac{1}{2}}\bigg[\bigg(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\bigg]'=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\dfrac{1}{2}}\bigg[\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\dfrac{1+2x}{2x+2x^2}\bigg]. $$
Let
$$ g(x)=\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\dfrac{1+2x}{2x+2x^2} $$
and then
$$ g'(x)=\frac{1}{2x^2(1+x)^2}>0. $$
So $g(x)$ is strictly increasing and hence for $1\le x<\infty$, $g(x)<g(\infty)=0$. This implies $f'(x)<0$ for $x\ge1$ or $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. Thus for $n<\infty$, $f(n)>f(\infty)=e$.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to prove that $\left(n+\dfrac12\right)\ln\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)\gt1$.

The function $f(x)=\left(x+\dfrac12\right)\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)$ has derivative
$f'(x)=\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)-\dfrac{2x+1}{2x^2+2x}$ so it is decreasing with
$f(1)\approx1.03972077$ and $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)}{\frac{1}{x+\frac12}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{-1}{x^2+x}}{\frac{-4}{(2x+1)^2}}=1$$ Therefore always $f(x)$ is greater than $1$ so $\left(n+\dfrac12\right)\ln\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)\gt1$ and
$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}>e$. We are done.

Comment: This looks very much like [@xpaul's answer 21 hours before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4797711/386889), expcept that you did not prove that $f'<0,$ and you uselessly approximated $f(1).$

Comment: What i wanted with the approximation of $f(1)$ is to show that the convergence to the limit is very slow.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Oliver I shall propose some hint to solve the problem :

Writing the function as :

$$g(x)=\left(1+1/x\right)^{x+1/2}=(1+1/x)^{x(1-a)+1/2}(1+a),a=0$$

Invert the variable we need to study :

$$f(x)=(1+1/a)^{a(1-x)+1/2}(1+x),x\simeq 0$$

Introduce the logarithm :

$$(\ln(f(x)))'=\frac{1}{x+1}-a\ln\left(1+1/a\right)$$

Setting $x=0$ in the derivative (we can use the Lambert's function to invert the function but it's another story) we have that the derivative (already shown) is decreasing  and positive so the function in $x$ is increasing around $x=0$.

The function in logarithmic form is also plus a minus almost completely monotone on $(0,\infty]$

$$h\left(0\right)+h'\left(0\right)x+\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{2}x^{2}+\frac{h'''\left(0\right)}{6}x^{3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{h^{\left(2n\right)}\left(0\right)}{\left(2n\right)!}x^{\left(2n\right)}\leq h(x)=\ln(f(x))\leq h\left(0\right)+h'\left(0\right)x+\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{2}x^{2}+\frac{h'''\left(0\right)}{6}x^{3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{h^{\left(2n+1\right)}\left(0\right)}{\left(2n+1\right)!}x^{\left(2n+1\right)}$$

So as the function is increasing $h'(x_{max})=0,h(x_{max})\geq h(0)$

$$ h(x_{max})=\ln(f(x_{max}))\leq h\left(0\right)+h'\left(0\right)x_{max}+\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{2}x_{max}^{2}+\frac{h'''\left(0\right)}{6}x_{max}^{3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{h^{\left(2n+1\right)}\left(0\right)}{\left(2n+1\right)!}x_{max}^{\left(2n+1\right)}$$

Or :

$$h(x_{max})-(h'\left(0\right)x_{max}+\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{2}x_{max}^{2}+\frac{h'''\left(0\right)}{6}x_{max}^{3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{h^{\left(2n+1\right)}\left(0\right)}{\left(2n+1\right)!}x_{max}^{\left(2n+1\right)})\leq h\left(0\right)$$

So :

$$h(x_{max})-(h'\left(0\right)x_{max}+\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{2}x_{max}^{2}+\frac{h'''\left(0\right)}{6}x_{max}^{3})\leq h(0)$$

One can show that the function where $x=x_{max}$ is decreasing in $a$ using the fact $p(x)=(1+1/x)^{1+x}$ is decreasing as :

$$P(x)=\left(1+\frac{2}{a}\right)^{1+a\left(1-x\right)}\left(1+x\right)^{2}$$

$P(x)$ is decreasing in $a$ as mentionned by the OP's post but as one can show :

$$\sqrt{P(x_{max})P(0)}-(P'\left(0\right)x_{max}+\frac{P''\left(0\right)}{2}x_{max}^{2})<\sqrt{2}\sqrt{P(x_{max})}$$

And by the mean value theorem $\exists k\in[-1/2,0]$ such that :

$$2<P(k)=\sqrt{P(x_{max})P(0)}-(P'\left(0\right)x_{max}+\frac{P''\left(0\right)}{2}x_{max}^{2})$$

So by a continuity argument $\sqrt{P(0)}$ is decreasing in $a$

Comment: Bonus : $$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+\frac{1}{2}}-e\coth\left(x+\frac{\pi}{e}\right)>0,x>0$$